# GLM angleAxis wrong?

Tags: c++, opengl, quaternions, glm-math

From tests of quaternions in OpenGL I noticed that rotations on multiple axis are not working how they should. So I wrote a simple program to debug that. This is my program:

```
glm::quat rotation = glm::angleAxis(glm::radians(45.0f), glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
glm::vec3 eulerRotation = glm::degrees(glm::eulerAngles(rotation));
printf("X = %f\tY = %f\tZ = %f\n", eulerRotation.x, eulerRotation.y, eulerRotation.z);
```

From my understanding of rotations this should output:

```
X = 45.0  Y = 45.0  Z = 0.0
```

But the program outputs this:

```
X = 51.589348   Y = 45.000004   Z = 18.939444
```

I'm using GLM version 0.9.9.5 and C++ 14
So, is my understanding of rotations wrong or is GLM screwing something up?

Comment: I did not verify that the angles you found are good or not, but note that the [Axis-Angle Representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation) is not the same as [Euler Angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) and the correct result looks more like the output of glm than your expectation.

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé Your article says: "The axis–angle representation is equivalent to the more concise rotation vector, also called the Euler vector"

Comment: The names make it very confusing, but the Euler Vector is not the same as a vector which contains Euler Angles.

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé Thanks for explaining that, can you please write that as answer so that I can close the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Axis-Angle Representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation) and the [Euler Angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) are two different ways of encoding a rotation. For rotations on canonical axes (X, Y, Z), the representations are very similar and can lead to the false deduction that the conversion is trivial. For example, the Axis-Angle `(45,(1,0,0))` is simply the Euler Angles `(45,0,0)`. However, for more general axes, the conversion is not always so obvious.

Adding to the confusion is that the name *Euler Vector* is used when we create a single 3D vector out of the Axis-Angle representation using the length of the vector to encode the angle of rotation. For example, `(45,(1,0,0))` can be encoded as `45*(1,0,0)`. However, an Euler Vector is not the same as a vector that contains Euler Angles for the same reason that the Axis-Angle representation is different from Euler Angles.

Finally, as stated in another answer by Amadeus, the *glm* framework requires that the input axis vector is normalized. Normalizing this vector will give the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

From [GLM_GTC_quaternion](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.4/api/a00153.html):

> glm::angleAxis:
>
> *Build a quaternion from an angle and a normalized axis.*
>
> Parameters
>
> - **angle**   Angle expressed in radians if GLM_FORCE_RADIANS is define or degrees otherwise.
> - **axis**  Axis of the quaternion, **must be normalized**.
>     (emphasis are mine)

You do not have a normalized axis in your snippet

Comment: I normalized but the result is this: `X = 35.264389 Y = 30.000002 Z = 9.735612`

Comment: To me, it seems correct. You can verify the rules for conversion between quaternion and euler angles here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles#Quaternion_to_Euler_Angles_Conversion. In particular, I have verified the Y angle and it gives 30

Comment: @user11914177 I verified on [this website](https://www.andre-gaschler.com/rotationconverter/) and the result is correct after normalization. Note that the correct Euler Angles order is ZYX.